# Is there a way to assign a member variable to an object of a class without a constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I want to do something like the following:

```
class SomeOtherClass {}

class Test
 {
        public $member = new SomeOtherClass();
 }
```

The only problem is that I do not want to use a constructor, because the 'Test' class should extend another class and should not override the constructor.
Is this actually possible in PHP?

Comment: No it's not possible. Member variables can only have constant expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *extend* parent constructor in `Test` like this:

```
class Test extends SomeClass
{
    public $member;

    function __construct() {
        $this->member = new SomeOtherClass();
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to force calling the parent constructor on child classes?

Comment: @Tom291, what does mean "to force calling the parent constructor"? do you want to automatically call the parent constructor on each child class without using `parent::__construct();` ?